# Not showing new form if one already exists

Tags: c#, forms, show

I have a button that brings up another form, but the way I do it

```
    hozzaadasForm HozzaadasForm;

    private void hozzaadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HozzaadasForm = new hozzaadasForm();
        HozzaadasForm.Show();
    }
```

Opens a new form, everytime I click the button, I don't really want that, but if I do it like this

```
    hozzaadasForm HozzaadasForm = new hozzaadasForm();

    private void hozzaadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HozzaadasForm.Show();
    }
```

Once I close it, I can't reopen it. (ObjectDisposedException was unhandled).
What can I do so it doesn't open a new one if one is already open, but I can open one, once I close it?

Comment: Do you need to re-execute the code in the form constructor and/or Form_Load event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you close the form, instead of actually closing it, you can call `Hide()`.

Answer (score 1):

In `HozzaadasForm`, subscribe to the `Closing` event, then cancel the close and hide the form instead:

```
private void HozzaadasForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;

    this.Hide();
}
```